# How do I add suggested results to my maps search bar on xcode 6 iOS8?

Tags: ios, xcode, maps

When the user types in the search bar I want it to show suggested results just like the Apple Maps app. This what is currently looks like when searching http://i.imgur.com/S2wMKkD.png. What I want it to like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmr2V.jpg

Also how do you get that greyish color to appear behind search bar and button as seen in the second image? When I tried adding a nav bar everything was restricted inside it (couldn't be moved) and the search bar was appeared behind the nav bar out of sight.

Thanks!

Comment: No one? Really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial pretty helpful http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_MapKit_Local_Search_in_iOS_8_and_Swift

Instead of adding annotation to the map, you can add the returned results to a table list.

OR this one may be exactly what you're looking for:

http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/02/16/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/